# React-router: Change URL and clear history

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following scenario:

A user opens an activation link; after the user has completed the activation process, the system will move them to another page.
I don't want to keep the activation link in the browser's history because when the the user goes back they will get to the activation step again.

***How do I replace the history of a browser to remove certain requests from my application?***

Comment: Finally, I can work around by these statements:

history.replaceState({}, document.title, url);
props.router.replace(url);

Answer (score 17):

In `ReactJs` you should use `browserHistory` for this purpose. This takes care of your histories and you don't need to implement those functions on your own.

browserHistory has 2 methods `push()` and `replace()` which do the same functions as @fazal mentioned in his answer but in a better way.

So if you want to avoid user going back to previous state you would need to use `browserHistory().replace`

Start with importing it into your code:

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router'
```

After user has activated you do following:-

```
browserHistory.replace(//your new link)
```

Comment: Hi, 

I tried this way, I still cannot rewrite url on the browser. (I know changing url is not a common behavior of the SPA app.)

Comment: Update: As of react-router v4, this will not work. Link: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 history API provide two methods to `Adding and modifying history entries`.

`pushState()` : back state preserved
`replaceState()` : no back state

Assuming you are using `react-router`.
So, on your Component use

```
this.props.history.replaceState('your new state')
```

read more: [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

video: [REACT JS TUTORIAL #6 - React Router & Intro to Single Page Apps with React JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s&index=6&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I have the following error `props.history.replaceState is not a function`

Comment: @Alfrex92 it's now `props.history.replace`

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but I had a similar issue and none of the other answers were 100% applicable with my version or `React` but this should work in more recent versions by clearing appended paths.

```js
   
  //replace(path, state)
  this.props.history.replace("/home", "urlhistory");
```

Comment: What is "urlhistory" ? I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get back one subdirectory no matter what the history is , you can do this

```
<Link to="./../" > .... </Link>
```

or

```
navigate("./../")
```

Answer (score -4):

Run this block where you want change route

```js
history.entries = [];
history.index = -1;
history.push(`/route`);
```

This will clear the history and change for a new one.

Answer (score -6):

```
window.location.href = 'Your path';
```

or

```
document.location.replace().
```

Comment: this answer is incomplete, please modify it and provide details