# Programmatically modify/manipulate browser history in react or vanillajs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So I have a SPA app, and wanted to make the browser history basically fresh when the user logs in.

Say I have a route '/' which has a link to login and register,
then when I go to '/login' and try to log in and got authenticated successfully, then the page mounts the authenticated page(s). Now, I wanted to remove '/' and '/login' from history, so the user wouldn't be able to go back to '/' or '/login' when day press back button on the browser

So far, I only have some sort of detection when the user is trying to go to unauthenticated pages (e.g. '/login') while authenticated. It would be convenient if I can programmatically remove the history before the authenticated page mounted, that way, first mounted page is the only history in the stack hence when they go back the user wouldn't be able to.

login.tsx:

```
const history = useHistory();
const login = useCallback(async(e: SubmitEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const result = await Service.login('route-that-handles-login');
  if (result.authenticated) {
    // this is where I intend to remove/manipulate the history before pushing to home.
    history.push('/home');
  }
}, [history]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router: Change URL and clear history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715324/react-router-change-url-and-clear-history)

Comment: apparently the link tells how to push and replace stuff but not remove. I guess there's no way to cleanly remove.